# How to check mutiple text fields for null values;

Tags: c#, .net

How can I check three different text fields for nulls?
I have the following code but it is giving an error.  Can you test for three different conditions in an if statement?

```
public bool IsFieldBlank(string fieldValue)
    {
        if (fieldValue != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool ValidateFields()
    {
//attempts to check all three fields but will not compile to do syntex
        if(IsFieldBlank(incidentTextBox.Text),IsFieldBlank(returnTextBox.Text),IsFieldBlank(actionTextBox.Text))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Booleans are a type.  You don't need to write code in the form `if(someBooleanStatement) return true; else return false;` just write `return(someBooleanStatement)`, i.e., `return(fieldValue != null);`

Comment: Simply put, you have commas as separators in your IF statement - whereas you actually need to logically compare them - either you want to check if ANY are empty or if ALL are empty (for the former use || OR, for the latter use && AND). And as stated below, string already has such a method, use it, it is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This is shorter:

```
return string.IsNullOrWhitespace(fieldValue);
```

If you are not on .NET 4.0 or above, you can use:

```
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldValue);
```

You will still have to check *each* field individually.

If you have these in a form, you can recursively iteration over the child control collection and for each control check if it is a `TextBox` (using the `is` keyword) and checking it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use to logical AND operator when doing a check like that.

```
if(IsFieldBlank(incidentTextBox.Text) && IsFieldBlank(returnTextBox.Text) &&IsFieldBlank(actionTextBox.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to change  your if statement from

```
    if(IsFieldBlank(incidentTextBox.Text),IsFieldBlank(returnTextBox.Text),IsFieldBlank    (actionTextBox.Text)) 
    { 
        return true; 
    }
```

to this:

```
    if((IsFieldBlank(incidentTextBox.Text))&&(IsFieldBlank(returnTextBox.Text))&&(IsFieldBlank(actionTextBox.Text))) 
    { 
        return true; 
    }
```

That will allow your code to compile. This will return true if all of your textboxes are blank. If you want it to return true if any of them are blank then you will need to use the OR operator ||

Answer (score 0):

```
 private bool ValidateFields()     
{ 
        return !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(incidentTextBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnTextBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionTextBox.Text));
 }
```